# Recharts stacked bar is painting many labels when rendering a total value for all stacked bars in one row/column. How to make it render just one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have an array data structure that I passed to the Recharts BarChart component. All values `dataX` for each `name` would be stacked into the same bar, and I want to show the total amount at the end of the bar.

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'nameA',
    data1: 30,
    data2: 30,
    total: 60,
  },
  // ...
];
```

The way I'm rendering the bars:

```js
const valueAccessor = (item) => (item ? item.total : 0);

const renderBars = () => {
  return parsedData.map(({name, dataKey, barName, color, renderShape}) => {
    <Bar
      key={`axis-${name}-${dataKey}`}
      dataKey={dataKey}
      stackId={barName}
      fill={color}
      shape={renderShape}
    >
      <LabelList valueAccessor={valueAccessor(barName)} position="right" />
    </Bar>
  });
}
```

I have different ways of rendering them with colors and probably would not need another data structure (see that renderBars uses `parsedData` instead of `data`, but that's something extra that I need to work on).

The output is this:

[image: stacked bar image]

As you can see, the numbers are kind of bold, and by inspecting them, I see that I can just remove the element and the number is still there, as 3 numbers are being rendered instead of 1. (because I have 3 stacked bars).

Is there any way of making recharts render just one label per row, instead of per stacked bar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After messing a little with the library, I found out that is inevitable to render 1 label when having 3 bars stacked per row/column. The only way of rendering a label is by setting the `LabelList` component as a child of a `Bar` component.

And if you have 2 bars, then you render a label for the first stacked bar, and then you don't render a label for the second stacked bar, in my case the label ended up not being rendered at all. So my only solution would be **just to render a `LabelList` for the last stacked bar per row/column**.

In the previous case, when having 3 stacked bars per row/column:

```js
const GROUPS = 3;

const valueAccessor = (item) => (item ? item.total : 0);

const renderBars = () => {
  return parsedData.map(({name, dataKey, barName, color, renderShape}) => {
    <Bar
      key={`axis-${name}-${dataKey}`}
      dataKey={dataKey}
      stackId={barName}
      fill={color}
      shape={renderShape}
    >
      {index % (parsedData.length / GROUPS) === (parsedData.length / GROUPS - 1) && 
 <LabelList valueAccessor={valueAccessor(barName)} position="right" />}
    </Bar>
  });
}
```

The same output only has 1 number per row (you can see the numbers are not "bold")

[image]